# what is the shortest way to do this thing on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I have and it works just fine but could you tell me if there is any short and clean coding way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('span#paylas_').click(function() {
        $('#uyri').slideUp();
        $('#dhda').slideUp();
        $('#pyls').slideToggle('normal');
    });
    $('span#uyari_').click(function() {
        $('#pyls').slideUp();
        $('#dhda').slideUp();
        $('#uyri').slideToggle('normal');
    });
    $('span#dahada_').click(function() {
        $('#pyls').slideUp();
        $('#uyri').slideUp();
        $('#dhda').slideToggle('normal');
    });     
});
```

Comment: it depends heavily on your html. So please post it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you give `data-toggle` attributes to your elements like this:

```
<span id="paylas_" data-toggle="#pyls"></span>
```

then you can combine the selectors and use `.data("toggle")` to get the appropriate selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var toggles = {};

    $('#paylas_, #uyari_, #dahada_').click(function() {
        var cached = this.id in toggles;

        if(!cached) {
            toggles[this.id] = $(this).data("toggle");
        }

        var toggle = toggles[this.id];

        $('#uyri, #dhda, #pyls').not(toggle).slideUp();
        $(toggle).slideToggle('normal');
     });
});
```

If you use `data-toggle` only for those elements, then you can also do:

```
$('[data-toggle]').click(function() {
```

I can't really make up something of the IDs but if there is a certain structure you could possibly generalize the second list of selectors as well.

Comment: @RonnieChesterLynwood: its `data-toggle` not `data-togle`

Comment: The `data-toggle` data can/should be cached on `document.ready` so it doesn't have to be calculated each click.

Comment: @Jasper: Good point, although I'm not sure if it's that big of a performance hit. I edited my answer.

Comment: `$('#paylas_, #uyari_, #dahada_').each(function (i, o) {toggles[this.id] = $(this).attr('data-toggle')}).click(...);` -- this will store all the necessary information on `document.ready` so no extra processing has to happen inside the `click` event handler.

Comment: @Jasper: Honestly, such optimization is only practical in e.g. `mousemove` since it's executed many times. In a `click` handler this seems overkill.

Comment: I always try to make every bit of code run as fast as it can since you never know how crappy a computer will be visiting your webpage.

Comment: okay one more question how can i use this with php's while loop? i've to do this in for each div generated by while i tried adding `data-id` to html and var `id = $(this).data("id");` to jquery and `$('#uyri'+id, '#dhda'+id, '#pyls'+id).not(toggle).slideUp();` this line but not worked -.-

Comment: @ Jasper: In that case you might be better off with plain JavaScript instead of jQuery. @Ronnie Chester Lynwood: I'm not sure but `id` is the same for all elements it seems.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {//notice the shorter document.ready declaration :)

    //setup a conversion from the clicked elements to the elements to slide up/down
    var convert = {
        paylas_ : '#pyls',
        uyari_  : '#uyri',
        dahada_ : '#dhda'
    };

    //select all the spans and bind the event handler to them, you can select multiple elements at once by separating the selectors with commas
    $('#paylas_, #uyari_, #dahada_').click(function() {

        //slide up all the spans except for the on associated with the currently clicked element
        $('#uyri, #dhda, #pyls').not(this).slideUp();

        //slide toggle the currently clicked element
        $(convert[this.id]).slideToggle('normal');
    });  
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yPxHq/1/

Comment: I gave you a +1, but I think it would be better off to only put the id names in the convert structure.  If there's ever any dynamic behavior in this page, then storing the jQuery objects (with DOM elements) may cause a memory leak.  Plus, this line `$('#uyri, #dhda, #pyls').not(convert[this.id]).slideUp();` doesn't need a  lookup.  It can just be this: `$('#uyri, #dhda, #pyls').not(this).slideUp();`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the suggestion. That makes good sense for the `.not()` selection, it seems like the last line, `convert[this.id]`, is probably faster than creating a jQuery object in the `click` event handler. Does that seem correct?

Comment: Sure it's faster to have precreated the jQuery objects, but speed for looking up one id in the DOM is irrelevant here vs. cleanliness of not storing DOM elements when not needed.  It's just starting an animation which is spread out over time and is kicked off by a user event - can't possibly be noticed.  I'd rather have faster page startup time too.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the cleanest way without chaining the HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#paylas_, #uyari_, #dahada_").click(function() {
        var ids = ["#uyri", "#dhda", "#pyls"],
        current = "#" + $(this)
            .attr("id")
            .replace(/_$/, "")
            .replace(/a(.)/g, "$1");
        delete ids[$.inArray(current, ids)];
        $(ids.join(",")).slideUp();
        $(current).slideToggle("normal");
    });
});
```

Edit: removed `span` in front

Comment: Why put span in front of your ids in the selector?  It just makes more work for the selector engine.

Comment: Good question! I don't know, I think I've just forgot that.

Comment: @jfriend00 I believe that if you want to support Internet Explorer 5.5 (lol, I know) then you need to use tag names in your selectors: http://docs.jquery.com/Known_Issues

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick refactor which may help a bit

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            clickFuntion("paylas","uyri","dhda","pyls");
            clickFuntion("uyari","pyls","dhda","uyri");
            clickFuntion("dahada","pyls","uyri","dhda");

            function clickFuntion(var1,va2,var3,var4){
             $('span#"+var1+"_').click(function() {
                $('#"+var2+"').slideUp();
                $('#"+var3+"').slideUp();
                $('#"+var4+"').slideToggle('normal');
            });

            }
    });
```